# Simulate from an AR(1) process where the parameters vary over time

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random

I would like to simulate from an AR(1) process, where the $\rho$ parameter in the process of the form:

$X_t = \rho X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

varies over time. The path of $\rho$ and $var(\epsilon_t)$ over time is pre-determined by some other process; for argument's sake here, let us say that the parameters are given beforehand in the lists:

```
listRho = RandomReal[1, {100}];
listSigma = RandomReal[1, {100}];
```

I know how to simulate from an AR(1) process (for example where $\rho=0.5$ and $var(\epsilon_t) = 1$) using:

```
 RandomFunction[ARProcess[0, {0.5}, 1]
```

However, does anyone know whether I can use the in-built functions, or otherwise, to allow $\rho$ and $var(\epsilon_t)$ to vary at each time step?

**Update**: I can simulate from an AR(1) manually using FoldList:

```
FoldList[0.5 #1 + #2 &, 0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]]
```

I have tried to allow the parameters of this process to vary over time using:

```
Reap[t = 1; FoldList[t++; Sow[t]; listRho[[t]] #1 + #2 &, 0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, listSigma[[t]]], {100}]]]
```

Where I use Reap and Sow to try to check whether $t$ is incrementing, but it does not appear to be.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Best,

Ben

Answer (score 2):

First let's define the needed variables:

```
n = 100;
ρ = RandomReal[1, {n}];
σ = RandomReal[1, {n}];
noise = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], n]*σ;
```

Note that in order to get the noise, I multiply a list of noises drawn from a standard normal by the standard deviations.  This is much faster than calling `RandomVariate` hundreds of times.  Now here's the actual data generation:

```
data = Rest@FoldList[{#1, 1}.#2 &, 0, Transpose[{ρ, noise}]]
```

First we transpose the list of parameters and noise values together.  This allows us to pass each pair of $(\rho_i,\epsilon_i)$ to the function in `FoldList`, without resorting to indexing.  We initialize with `0`.  The function itself takes the dot product `{#1, 1}.#2`, which is simply `{x[i-1], 1}.{ρ[i],ε[i]}`; so we get `x[i] = x[i-1]ρ[i] + ε[i]`.  If you want to add a constant (time-varying or not), simply add it to the noise vector.

Comment: Thanks for that. I really appreciate the time taken to write the answer! Much better than mine. Best, Ben

Comment: I did a quick timing comparison when I saw your answer (I started writing this answer before yours got posted).  Mine is around 4.5 times faster generating 1M datapoints.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for doing that. I concede! Best, Ben

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do this, and have checked that all is working as should be, using Reap and Sow.

First, we generate the lists, and use the $\sigma$ one to generate the error list:

```
listSigma = RandomReal[1, {10}];
listRho = RandomReal[1, {10}];
lError = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, #]] & /@ listSigma;
Thread[{listRho, lError}]
```

I have included the last bit with Thread, so that we can compare it with the entries from Reaping and Sowing, when we run the AR(1) process below:

```
FNew[rho_, xPast_, error_] := Module[{}, Sow[{rho, error}]; t++; rho xPast + error]
Reap[t = 1; FoldList[FNew[listRho[[t]], #1, #2] &, 0, lError]][[2]]
Reap[t = 1; FoldList[FNew[listRho[[t]], #1, #2] &, 0, lError]][[1]]
```

The first reaping/sowing yields the same parameters as from the threading, indicating that the parameters are being updated at each time step. The latter reap/sow yields the AR(1) process.

Hope this helps someone else!

Best,

Ben